# Neovim clangd LSP outdated compared with the clang compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, neovim

I encountered this problem when I tried to declare an initialized vector in C++. I am new to C++, so I thought nothing much about it when I got an error in neovim (my code editor) that I could not declare a initzialised vector.
This is about what it looked like:

```cpp
std::vector<int> test_vector = {1, 5, 9}   // ERROR: non-aggregate type "std::vector<int>"...
```

I tried searching up the error, because I thought I had done something wrong. And then I found out that that error only was true in older versions of C++ (C++98 and C++03). But I knew I had a newer clang version than that. So I compiled the program and it ran.
So my question is: "Why is my "editor compiler" outdated from my "system compiler", and how do I fix it (update the editor compiler)"

I hope I was clear with my explenation, as I struggle with that.

Comment: Do you have your project's `.clangd` file have the `CompileFlags:` have `Add: [-std=c++20]`?

Comment: That fixed it! I just added what you said to a file named compie_flags.txt in the root directory of the folder "-std=c++20".